# Need help understanding this operation

Tags: pointers, struct, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I am reading a document given to me by a professor and I'm trying to understand the following line of code.

> C *r = new(p) C[3];

what exactly is the code doing? What does the C[3]  after the new(p) accomplish?

Comment: See placement new operator: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code constructs an array of 3 items of type `C`, similar to this, which is hopefully more familiar to you:

```
C *r = new C[3];
```

The primary difference is that `new(p)` does not allocate new memory; instead it constructs the array in a pre-existing memory buffer pointed by `p`. For example:

```
char *p = new char[3*sizeof(C)];
C *r = new(p) C[3];
```

Another difference is that you can't use `delete[]` to call the deconstructors and free the memory. You have to call the deconstructors manually

```
for (int i=0; i<3: i++) r->~C();
delete[] p;
```

See also [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).